# Shut off tub water behind wall

Tags: plumbing

[image]

How can I shut off water to shower only?  Or is it bkr possible?  I don't see a shut off valve, am I missing it?  This picture is the back of my tub where wall was remixed.

I want to cut off only shower water as of right now, the hot water coming into water heater is off.  We need it on for dishwasher.

Cheers

Comment: The shower valves outside the wall are under your control. Why would you want to shut it off inside the wall? What do you mean "the hot water coming into water heater is off"? Cold water goes *into* and hot water comes out.

Comment: no there is not ordinarily a valve to shut off water to just the shower. What is the actual problem?

Comment: So the cold water that comes into hot water is off then. Although that confuses me because the cold water in tub can still be turned on by the cold water handle where as the hot is indeed off unless I open valve on water heater.

Comment: The problem is we bought a house a couple weeks ago.  The hot and cold water knobs were laying there pulled off.  They had been stripped.  The hot water valve mechanism (don't know correct jargon) is stuck in the on position.  So if I open the valve at the water heater, it just releases water into the tub continuously.  We can't use the dishwasher right now until this is fixed.  I'm trying to turn just the shower off.

Comment: You can get special handles which attach to a stripped valve stem. This type has a knife inside which bites into the brass stem and allows the valve to be used.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's best if you edit this important information into your question, rather than posting it as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate fault is that the hot water valve is stuck open. Get some pliers and try to shut the hot water valve on the tub/shower. Locking pliers (Vise-Grips) would be easiest, but you could use regular pliers or a pipe wrench.

Note that you will have to determine which direction to turn it off. Some of these shower valves have "counter rotating valves" in which the cold is turned off one way (usually CW) and the hot the other way (usu CCW). But in some shower valves both close the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily cap off the shower with a 1/2" FNPT pipe cap attached where the shower head would go, or install a shower head with an on/off switch.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I would plan to replace that shower valve, sooner rather than later.  It is understood that you turn the whole house off to do any extensive work on a tub/shower valve.  Always has been.  Hopefully you can get the previously owners to defray the cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can most likely replace the valve cartridges for the shower and fix the problem. Best to do that in pairs while you're at it so you know both are good for the foreseeable future. It's not complicated or hard to do and there are videos on YouTube that will show you how.

The hard part would be ascertaining exactly what cartridges you need. See if you have manufacturer's marks or branding on the visible parts of the faucets or handles. If you can't find any identifying features like that, you should be able to figure it out by removing one/both and taking them to a home center or plumbing supply store to match up.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here is cut into the wall and replace the pressure connection valve and ma sure that your new one has in-valve stops. These are little screw-looking things that when you use a Phillips screw driver you can shut the tub off. It requires access from the wall behind the shower/tub so for future needs I would suggest coming up with an easy-access idea that allows you to open the area in the event of a future emergency. Many people rely on handles alone but they wear down and break and when you least expect it, the water will no longer shut off. It's worth the investment instead of a high water bill and the inability to have running water.
PS do not buy a pressure valve connector that says ( no stop) it does not have the built in vslves

Comment: Welcome Jessica!  What is the last word in your answer supposed to be?